# Ionic storage Vs sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, ionic3, storage, ionic-storage

I new to ionic 3 where i need to maintain an offline data in the respective storage and persists data when network comes back.

I gone through a lot of research among which one to choose weather to use ionic storage which uses Cordova sqlite in the background which stores data in the form of key value pairs or sqlite to write queries and store data in the form of tables.
Which one more efficient when handling offline data?
Suppose I need save a single object out of 100. I suppose to write a query to select that object or I need to iterate for 100 times to select the Appropriate object?

Please mention in comments below if my question is not clear.

Comment: in this link there is information about this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/native-storage-local-storage-or-sqlite/101822/5